# Capturar texto entre comillas de un textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo en javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function obtenerTextoEnComillas() {
    const regex = /"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g,
          texto = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    var   grupo,
          resultado = [];
    
    while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //si coincide con comillas dobles, el contenido estará en el
        //   grupo[1], con el grupo[2] undefined, y viceversa
        resultado.push(grupo[1] || grupo[2]);
    }
    
    //resultado es un array con todas las coincidencias
    // mostramos los valores separados con saltos de línea
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado.join("\n");
}
</script>
```

```html
Texto:
<textarea id="ingreso" style="width:100%" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Obtener texto entre comillas" onclick="obtenerTextoEnComillas()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Necesito una expresion regular que capture lo que esta entre comillas dobles de este texto:

[Result "1-0"]

[Country "USA"]

"Otro texto...."

Solo obtener 1-0 el resultado entre: **[Result "** y **"]** y omitir el resto de comillas dobles.

Seria una expresion regular que solo capture lo que esta entre **[Result "** y **"]**

Muchas gracias!

Saludos.

Comment: Bien jugado! como lo haces evitas el dilema de la máquina de pila... de abrir y cerrar operadores...

Comment: Yo lo ejecuté y me devolvió las coincidencias, cúal es el error?

Comment: Hola, me refiero tengo este texto:

[Result "1-0"]

[Country "USA"]

"Otro texto...."

Y me de resultado 1-0 solo lo que esta dentro de [Result " y "]

Cambiar la expresion regular.

Comment: Mira este validador, https://rubular.com/r/yJmYmjapaUrLM9  , veo que la RegExp no valida el caracter de control, necesitas validarlo?

Comment: Gracias Fabio por tu respuesta, pero necesito una expresion regular que capture lo que esta entre [Result " y "] solamente y de resultado solo 1-0, y omita lo demas comillas dobles del texto.

Comment: Puedes quitar el modificagor g de la variable regexp, por ejemplo : /[a-zA-Z]+/g ->  /[a-zA-Z]+/

Comment: Mira este ejemplo:  https://rubular.com/r/qFfAvupWAaWlQP

Comment: Con ese ejemplo me captura todos los textos que estan entre comillas dobles "", lo que necesito es capturar lo que esta entre [Result " y "] solamente con una expresion regular.

Comment: Me ha quedado claro : Intenta este : \[Result[ ]+"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'\]   https://rubular.com/r/ksW3AODiagnKOU

Comment: Perfecto, es justo lo que queria, muchas gracias por tu respuesta Fabio Palm ahora si devuelve el resultado que esperaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esto :
...
const regex = /[Result[ ]+"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)']/g,
...

Comment: Perfecto, es justo lo que queria, muchas gracias por tu solucion Fabio Palm ahora si devuelve el resultado que esperaba.

Comment: La expresion que me funciono fue esta: const regex =  /Result "([^"]*)"/g

Comment: el editor me removió caracteres, estoy arreglando el post.

Comment: Bien, gracias nuevamente.